# put page breaks and scrolling to print dynamic html webview data UIPrintInfo

Tags: html, iphone, objective-c, webview

I am doing project which has a facility to print webview data. In webview I am printing HTML content this ids dynamic data not a static. But my problem is I am not able to print complete data. Even I am not able to scroll. Here is my code:
[image: This is my print. not printing completly its only printing one page]
        - (NSString *)generateHTMLBodyForPrint

```
{
    if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
    res = @"<html><body><table style='border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:85%;col-width:95;margin-left:2cm';font-family:'GoodDogPlain';col-height:30;>";
    }
   else
   {
        res = @"<html><body><table style='border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;col-width:120;margin-left:2cm';font-family:'GoodDogPlain';col-height:30;>";
   }

    res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<tr height='50';width='100'>"];

    res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th style='border:1px solid black;height:30;width:100' >DATE, TIME</th>"];
    res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th style='border:1px solid black;height:30;width:100';> GOAL </th>"];
    res  = [res stringByAppendingString:@"<th style='border:1px solid black;'>% CORRECT ON OWN</th>"];
    res  = [res stringByAppendingString:@"<th style='border:1px solid black;'>% CORRECT WITH HELP</th>"];

    res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</tr>"];


    for (int i=0; i<[scoreDetailsArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict=[scoreDetailsArray objectAtIndex:i];

               NSString *date=nil;
        NSString *time=nil;

        NSString *rawString = [dict valueForKey:@"notes"];
        NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
        NSString *trimmed = [rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
        //NSLog(@"trimed%@",trimmed);
        //NSLog(@"trimed%@",[dict valueForKey:@"notes"]);


        NSArray *dateArry = [[dict valueForKey:@"maximumdate"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

        if([dateArry count] == 3)
        {
            str = [[[[[[dateArry objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@""] stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:[dateArry objectAtIndex:1]] stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:[dateArry objectAtIndex:2]];

            //  //NSLog(@"final date ******%@",str);
        }
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@"pm"];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@"am"];


        // NSArray* dateParts = [[dict valueForKey:@"maximumdate"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

        date = [dateArry objectAtIndex:0];
        //NSLog(@"%@",date);

        time = [dateArry objectAtIndex:1];


        if([trimmed length] ==0)
        {



            //--maximumdate and time


            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<tr height='50'>"];

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td style='border:1px solid black;width:40;'align='center';height='100'><p>"];
            //NSLog(@"str**** %@",str);

            NSArray *dateParts = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
            date = [dateParts objectAtIndex:0];
            time = [dateParts objectAtIndex:1];

            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:date];
            //   //NSLog(@"date==%@",date);
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</p><p>"];

            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:time];
            //  //NSLog(@"time==%@",time);

            res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@"pm"];
            res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@"am"];

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</p></td>"];


            // res  = [res stringByAppendingString:str];
            // res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td>"];



            //---goal name

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td style='border:1px solid black;width:50;'align='center';>"];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:[dict valueForKey:@"goalname"]];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td>"];

            //----correct on own

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td style='border:1px solid black;width:50;'align='center';>"];
            NSString *perValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d, %d%@",[[dict valueForKey:@"correctans"] intValue],[[dict valueForKey:@"totalans"] intValue],[[dict valueForKey:@"ownpercentage"] intValue],@"%"];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:perValue];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td>"];

            //----correct with help

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td style='border:1px solid black;width:50;'align='center';>"];
            NSString *helpValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d,""  "" %d%%",([[dict valueForKey:@"helpattempt"] integerValue] + [[dict valueForKey:@"correctans"] integerValue]),[[dict valueForKey:@"totalans"] integerValue] ,[[dict valueForKey:@"helppercentage"] intValue]];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:helpValue];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td></tr>"];

        }
        else
        {
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<tr height='50'>"];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td rowspan='2' style='border:1px solid black;width:40;'align='center';height='100'><p>"];



            NSArray *dateParts = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
            date = [dateParts objectAtIndex:0];
            time = [dateParts objectAtIndex:1];

            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:date];
            //NSLog(@"date==%@",date);
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</p><p>"];

            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:time];
            //NSLog(@"time==%@",time);

            res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@"pm"];
            res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@"am"];

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</p></td>"];

            /*   res  = [res stringByAppendingString:date];
             res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</p><p>"];
             res  = [res stringByAppendingString:time];

             res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@"pm"];
             res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@"am"];
             res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</p></td>"]; */



            //---goal name

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td style='border:1px solid black;width:50;'align='center';>"];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:[dict valueForKey:@"goalname"]];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td>"];

            //----correct on own

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td style='border:1px solid black;width:50;'align='center';>"];
            NSString *perValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d, %d%@",[[dict valueForKey:@"correctans"] intValue],[[dict valueForKey:@"totalans"] intValue],[[dict valueForKey:@"ownpercentage"] intValue],@"%"];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:perValue];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td>"];

            //----correct with help

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td style='border:1px solid black;width:50;'align='center';>"];
            NSString *helpValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d,""  "" %d%%",([[dict valueForKey:@"helpattempt"] integerValue] + [[dict valueForKey:@"correctans"] integerValue]),[[dict valueForKey:@"totalans"] integerValue] ,[[dict valueForKey:@"helppercentage"] intValue]];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:helpValue];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td></tr>"];


            // notes progress import- Start -/////

            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<tr><td  colspan='3' style='border:1px solid black;width:50;'align='left';>Notes:  "];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingString:[dict valueForKey:@"notes"]];
            res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td></tr>"];

            /// notes progress import -End

        }

    }
    //<div style="background-color:orange;text-align:center">
    res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</table><div style='margin-left:2cm;background-color:white'><small>Scores provided by Artic Fun</small></div>"];
   // res= [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<div style='margin-left:2cm'><small>Scores provided by Artic Fun</small></div>"];

    res= [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<div style='margin-left:2cm;background-color:white'>"];

    res= [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"<a style=\"text-decoration:none\" href=\"http://www.puddytatspeech.com\"><small>www.puddytatspeech.com</small></a></div>"];

    res  = [res stringByAppendingFormat:@"</body></html>"];
    // //NSLog(@"res***** %@",res);

    return res;

}
-(IBAction)printAction:(id)sender
{
    emailBody = [self generateHTMLBodyForPrint];
    NSString *printTitle = @"Articulation records for ";
    NSString *player;
    NSString *appendString;
    for (int i=0; i<[scoreDetailsArray count]; i++)
    {
        Playerinfo *info = [playerNameArry objectAtIndex:currentRowIndex];
        player  = info.playername;
    }
        appendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", printTitle,player];

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<br margin-top:'2cm'>%@</br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font face='Helvetica' color='black' size='4'>%@</font><p style='line-height: 125'>%@",@"",appendString,emailBody];

    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 6.5 * 72, 9 * 72)];
    [_webView loadHTMLString: html baseURL: nil];
    _webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
   // _webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if(!controller){
        //NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
        return;
    }

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if(!completed && error){
            //NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        }
    };


    // Obtain a printInfo so that we can set our printing defaults.
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    // This application produces General content that contains color.
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;

    // We'll use the URL as the job name.
       // Set duplex so that it is available if the printer supports it. We are
    // performing portrait printing so we want to duplex along the long edge.
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    // Use this printInfo for this print job.
    controller.printInfo = printInfo;

    // Be sure the page range controls are present for documents of > 1 page.
    controller.showsPageRange = YES;

    // This code uses a custom UIPrintPageRenderer so that it can draw a header and footer.
    APLPrintPageRenderer *myRenderer = [[APLPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
    // The APLPrintPageRenderer class provides a jobtitle that it will label each page with.
  //  myRenderer.jobTitle = printInfo.jobName;
    //NSLog(@"jobTitle==%@",myRenderer.jobTitle);
    // To draw the content of each page, a UIViewPrintFormatter is used.
    UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [_webView viewPrintFormatter];
#if SIMPLE_LAYOUT
    /*
     For the simple layout we simply set the header and footer height to the height of the
     text box containing the text content, plus some padding.

     To do a layout that takes into account the paper size, we need to do that
     at a point where we know that size. The numberOfPages method of the UIPrintPageRenderer
     gets the paper size and can perform any calculations related to deciding header and
     footer size based on the paper size. We'll do that when we aren't doing the simple
     layout.
     */
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:HEADER_FOOTER_TEXT_HEIGHT];
    CGSize titleSize = [myRenderer.jobTitle sizeWithFont:font];
    myRenderer.headerHeight = myRenderer.footerHeight = titleSize.height + HEADER_FOOTER_MARGIN_PADDING;
#endif
    [myRenderer addPrintFormatter:viewFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
    // Set our custom renderer as the printPageRenderer for the print job.
    controller.printPageRenderer = myRenderer;
    [controller presentFromRect:CGRectMake(670, 620, 500, 500) inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```